# Problem passing std::string though DLL boundaries with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, stl, dllexport

I have a DLL that contains some code like this:

```
class Info {
    int a
    int b
    int c
    std::string str1;
    std::string str2;
};

__declspec(dllexport) class C {
    Info getInfo();
}
```

I compile this code with Visual Studio 2015, and calling `C::getInfo()` works perfectly fine on my system.

Now somebody else is trying to use the DLL, and he's also using Visual Studo 2015. The call goes well but the strings don't contain any accessible data. Even the debugger reports "Error reading characters of string", and the program crashes when trying to read it.

There was also a similar problem with `std::vector` which I could solve by inlining the code that created the vector.

To me this looks like either the other person is using a different STL version, or the compiler somehow produces a different memory layout for `std::string` (though he claims to use default settings).

Is this possible? I saw there are different updates for VS 2015 and we might not have the same updates installed.

Any recommendations for fixing this? I can't move to `char*` without significantly breaking the API. Most users don't even use Visual Studio (or Windows), so this hasn't been a problem until now.

Comment: Needs [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to use proper flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library

Comment: Are you sure there is no mixing of debug and release? Meaning you must supply a debug dll and a release dll separately and the user has to use the correct ones.

Comment: ... and no mixing between 64- and 32-bit compilation?

Comment: Yes it should work as long as you use the same runtime version. Updates shouldn't matter. Make sure that the toolset is actually set to "VC140" and that you are using the same runtime link type as Dan posted above (you can't mix debug and release code).

Comment: @Aconcagua that wouldn't run at all

Comment: Compiling both with /MD?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Would mixing debug/release? It's been a while since I've (been forced to) use(d) MSVC the last time, believe to remember that release exe refused to load debug dll and vice versa as well...

Comment: Modern Visual Studio should complain about inconsistent `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` if you mix debug and release. However I believe a user can force it to still work.

Comment: *Any recommendations for fixing this* -- This is the deal you made with the devil when you decided to use objects across EXE boundaries.  Any differences in the DLL and EXE settings, even ones you may not know about now, can cause these issues.

Comment: @Aconcagua as far as I remember static libraries will fail to link (due to duplicate symbols), dlls link but then don't behave correctly at runtime

Comment: @drescherjm debug and release could be an issue. I always assumed that this would not affect the ABI.

Comment: The runtimes of debug and release are incompatible. In debug mode there are extra data in the standard library and in the runtime to aid in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

That's life I'm afraid. Unless you have *exactly* the same compiler (including C++ Standard Library) and compiler settings, this is not guaranteed to work. I'm not convinced from a C++ Standards perspective that even this is guaranteed to work. It's pretty nigh on impossible to build an ABI in C++. In your specific example, there's no guarantee that the `struct` will be built with the same alignment characteristics. `sizeof(std::string)` varies considerably due in part to short string optimisations which can even be compiler-configurable.

Alternatives:

1. Use C linkage for your exported functions and char*-style interfaces that are allocated and deallocated by the caller (cf. the Windows API). (Don't ever allocate memory in the client and deallocate in the dll, and vice-versa.)
2. Make sure the user of your library can build it from the source files. Consider distributing as a static library rather than a dynamic one, as the former are a little easier to work with.